# A 3D plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I have two variables which i sweep, `W1` and `W3`. I made a nested loop of these two variables.

```
for i=1:size(W1,2) 
    for j=1:size(W3,2)
         d(i,j)=someexpression(W1(i),W3(j))
    end
end
```

I want to do a 3D plot with `W1` in the x-axis and `W3` in the y-axis and d should be in the z-axis so that I have a 3D plot (or some contour plot).

EDIT: The 3d plot should actually be a surface

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like `plot3(W1,W3,d)` for instance? Or `surf`

Comment: yes but it doesn't display what i want. The 3D plot should actually be a surface. And since you don't have all points of the surface I assume that MATLAB will have to do some interpolation. EDIT: Aah ok, surf did the job, never heard of that one. thanks :)

Comment: Ok then please provide a minimal working example and show what you get and why this is not what you want; that will help better answer your question. You can post links to images and someone will upload them for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the interpolation manually:

```
x = linspace(W1(1), W1(end), 100);
y = linspace(W2(1), W2(end), 100);
z = interp2(W1, W2, d, x, y);
surf(x, y, z)
```

Comment: One suggestion I have is to use `scatteredInterpolant`.  It essentially does the above under the hood.  `F = scatteredInterpolant(W1, W2, d); z = F(x, y); surf(x, y, z);`. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html .  However, good answer nonetheless!